# How do I make TextEdit remember last Save As location in Mountain Lion?

Tags: defaults, textedit

First off, I have disabled iCloud as default location for Save As dialogs in TextEdit.app:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud -bool false`

… But still, I have one critical beef in TextEdit:

Save As… dialogs don't remember the **last location** where I saved a file! To the best of my knowledge, this used to be the case prior to (Mountain) Lion.

How can I restore this behavior?

---

Example use case:

1. Open TextEdit.
2. Type something.
3. Hit `⌘W`.
4. Save As dialog appears; choose ~/Desktop.
5. Quit and reopen TextEdit.
6. Repeating steps 1–3 … it doesn't default to ~/Desktop! (It's always ~/Documents.)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. I also tried disabling NSNavPanelExpandedStateForSaveMode and enabling iCloud document storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is software that can track this folder and augment the standard behavior that you are seeing.

I find Default Folder to be the best of class, and you can try it for free and then decide if it's worth paying once you've had a chance to kick the tires a bit.

http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/